# New TD D-Series funds: are they worth considering (unknown expense ratios)?

Tags: investing, canada, mutual-funds, expense-ratio

I am currently a holder of [TD's e-Series funds](https://www.tdcanadatrust.com/products-services/investing/mutual-funds/td-eseries-funds.jsp) in my investment portfolio.

However, the other day, I came across a [**new series of funds offered by TD: D-Series funds**](http://www.tdwaterhouse.ca/products-services/investing/td-direct-investing/investment-types/mutual-funds/low-cost-solutions.jsp).

From what I can tell, the funds are too new to have their expense ratios published. However, as an example, [this D-Series fund states](https://www.tdassetmanagement.com/Fund-Document/pdf/Fund-Facts/TD-Mutual-Funds/TDB3048E.pdf):

- Annual management fee of up to **1.10%**
- Administration fee is **0.30%**
- Trailer fee of up to **0.25%**

If I understand correctly, this adds up to nearly **1.70%** which isn't really low cost. Perhaps, it is considered low cost compared to other advisor based mutual funds in Canada.

**Now for my actual question:** D-Series funds launched in February 2015. How is it possible that a fund doesn't have a published expense ratio after almost half a year of operations? As an investor, how do I know what I am getting in to?